# Same width of few ggplots combined with grid.arrange function

Tags: r, ggplot2, width

Is there a way to set a width for a ggplot?

I am trying to combine three timeplots in one column.
Because of y-axis values, plots have different width (two plots have axis values within range (-20 , 50), one (18 000, 25 000) - which makes plot thiner).
I want to make all plots exactly the same width.

```
plot1<-ggplot(DATA1, aes(x=Date,y=Load))+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("Load [MWh]") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%y"),breaks = date_breaks("months"))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = "white") )
plot2<-ggplot(DATA1, aes(x=Date,y=Temperature))+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("Temperature [C]") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%y"),breaks = date_breaks("months"))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = "white") )
plot3<-ggplot(DATA1, aes(x=Date,y=WindSpeed))+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("Wind Speed [km/h]") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%y"),breaks = date_breaks("months"))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = "white") )
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, nrow=3)
```

Combined plot looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: I like `?cowplot::plot_grid` better than `grid arrange` because of stuff like this, might be worth a look

Comment: @NathanDay thanks :) I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use facetting for this. First you have to do some data munging:

```
library(tidyr)

new_data = gather(DATA1, variable, value, Load, Temperature, WindSpeed)
```

this gathers all the data in `Load`, `Temperature` and `Windspeed` into one big column (`value`). In addition, an extra column is created (`variable`) which specifies which value in the vector belongs to which variable.

After that you can plot the data:

```
ggplot(new_data) + geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = value)) + 
   facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = 'free_y', ncol = 1)
```

Now ggplot2 will take care of all the heavy lifting.

ps If you make you question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I can make my answer reproducible.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for :) By making my question reproducible did you mean adding my data set?

Comment: You should be aware that the method in this answer does not take into account that the variables have different units.  You'll have to individually set the y-axis labels to incorporate the difference in units using 'annotate'

Comment: @JakeKaupp, thanks I used 'gsub' to change the variable name for one with unit in it. (new_data$variable <- gsub("Load", "Load MWh",new_data$variable) It worked fine :)

Comment: Great, just as long as you're aware!

Comment: @ppi0trek adding data indeed.